# Activating UIImageView with GestureRecognizer in a ScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I,

I'm currently trying to implement a Gesture recognizer into a ScrollView.

I first created a custom ScrollView in which I integrated ImageView object.

When the user clicks on a ImageView, normally the PanGestureRecognizer activates and the ImageView object follow the move on the screen.

I have read and followed the instructions on Gesture Recognizer and the Raywenderlich blog (which is very well done).

If someone has a clue of what is missing in my code, I would be happy to read it

Thank in advance. Here is my code

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "mainInterface03.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "boutonHome.h"
#import "DragGestureRecognizer.h"

@class boutonHome;
@class DragGestureRecognizer;

@interface TapScrollView : UIScrollView {

   // id<TapScrollViewDelegate> delegate;
    NSMutableArray *classementBoutons;
    int n;
    int o;
    UIView *bouton01;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *bouton01;

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSMutableSet* buttons;

-(id)init;
-(void)initierScrollView;

-(void) createGestureRecognizers;
-(IBAction)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender;


@end
```

m.file

```
#import "TapScrollView.h"


@implementation TapScrollView


@synthesize bouton01;


- (id) init 
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        NSLog(@"Classe TapScrollView initiée");
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)initierScrollView
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<6; i++) {

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"];
        UIImageView *bouton = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        [bouton setTag:i];
        [bouton setFrame:CGRectMake(72*i+20,10,62,55)];
        [classementBoutons insertObject:bouton atIndex:i];
        [self addSubview:bouton];
        }

        UIPanGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:bouton01 action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];
        [bouton01 addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];

}
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{    
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

    for (o=1; o<6; o++) {
    if ([touch view] ==  [self viewWithTag:o]) 
    {
    bouton01 = [self viewWithTag:o];
    }
    }

    return;
}



-(IBAction)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"Mouvement ok");
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self];
    recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x, 
                                         recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self];

}
@end
```

Comment: You did not tell us what is not working...

Comment: sorry the imageviews are here but I cant move them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this setup can work. Essentially, you are assigning whatever view has been touched to `bouton01`, which carries the gesture recognizer. Seems a bit convoluted to me, and also your code is not so efficient.

It seems that when you call `[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];` it will pass the touch up the view hierarchy. Only after that do make the assignment to `bouton01`. So it would seem logical that `bouton01` never receives a touch event.

Indeed, it is because of this strange approach of iterating through the views and assigning it the one that has the recognizer that this error arose. I would suggest to assign the same recognizer to all concerned views during setup.